# for each id na in value

Tags: r, dplyr

I have dataframe:

```
id    value
19      56
19      56
19      56
19      98
19      98
```

The id column has many different meanings, not just 19. I need to do this:

```
id    value
19     56
19     NA
19     NA
19     98
19     NA
```

And so for each id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `replace()`:

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(test = replace(value, duplicated(value), NA))
#     id value  test
#  <int> <int> <int>
#1    19    56    56
#2    19    56    NA
#3    19    56    NA
#4    19    98    98
#5    19    98    NA
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `duplicated` from `base R` to create a logical index to assign the 'value' to `NA`

```
df1$value[duplicated(df1)] <- NA
df1
#  id value
#1 19    56
#2 19    NA
#3 19    NA
#4 19    98
#5 19    NA
```